# catkin_create_rosjava_pkg

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I have installed ros-hydro and rosjava, but when I try to create a rosjava package I get.

$ catckin_create_rosjava_pkg rosjava_foo
[error] [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosjava_build_tools/templates/rosjava_package/CMakeLists.txt.in' : <type 'exceptions.IOError'>

I don't understand what is the problem.

Please give me a feedbak,

Roberta

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89011/catkin_create_rosjava_pkg/) by [rperro88](https://answers.ros.org/users/7511/rperro88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like a bug:
https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_build_tools/issues/4

Until it's fixed, maybe catkin_create_android_pkg can help you a bit, though you will have to manually change some lines of the result.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0